# What do I need to know before running a glmm?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, glmm, similarities

I have a dataset that I want to run a glmm on. The question that I hope to investigate with the glmm is whether there is any relationship between the similarities between two bird calls, and how far apart they were recorded (i.e. do these particular bird calls change with distance). I have the following information;

> [1] "Call1"    "Call2"    "Value"    "Distance" "Date.Dif" "Time.Dif"

Where Call1 and Call2 are the file names of the two recordings that were compared, "Value" is a percentage indicating how similar the two are, "Distance" is the distance between the recording location of the two calls, "Date.Dif" is the difference (in days) between when the recordings were made (if one was recorded two days after the other, this value would be 2), "Time.Dif" is the difference in recording times (e.g. 8:00AM compared to 4:00PM is a 8:00 difference).

Every Call2 is compared against every Call1, so I want to use Call1 as a random effect (because each will have different baseline similarities), and test the rest of the variables as fixed effects, to test if they make a difference. However, this is the first time I've attempted to use a glmm, and was hoping I could get some general advice about how to prepare this data and run the tests. I'm planning to use glmer in R as below.

> glmer.calls <- glmer(Value~Distance+Date.Dif+Time.Dif(1|Call1), data = calls.data)

Is this the appropriate way to analyse this data? Are there any tests I need to run before performing this test?